# How to restrict access to some photos within a shared album in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, photo-sharing, google-plus-photos

I uploaded some vacation pictures to Google Plus in an album. Is it possible to share a selected few photos from the album with my friend Mr.X? Will they be able to see the whole album if I share one or two photos from an album?

In other words, can I restrict access to some photos in a shared album?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google+ album can have just one sharing setting at a time.

- But you can choose and share only selected photos from that album, then the recipient can see only those images, not the whole album - as Google+ creates a new album for those shared photos.  The rest stays private.

You can also move / copy those selected photos to a new album with wider sharing settings.

*Note: If you tag someone in a photo inside an album, they see all the photos in that album.*

Read more from Google+ Photos support:
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1407859?hl=en&ref_topic=1257351

An article about Google+ photos, albums and how to organize them:
http://googleplushelper.blogspot.fi/2013/06/google-and-your-photos.html